# How to properly implement recursive functions in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm writing a code which evaluate functions of step n depending of their values on previous step. I'm trying to solve it via recursion. Here is some code

```
Clear["Global`*"];

ResourcesToPower[x_] := Log[1.1, x/10 + 1]/Log[1.1, 2]*10;
ProvincePower = ConstantArray[50, 10];
ProvinceResources[p_] := ProvincePower[[p]]*10;

PlayerResources[0] = 50;
PlayerResources[n_] := 
  PlayerResources[n] = 
   PlayerResources[n - 1] + ProvinceResources[PlayerProvince[n - 1]];

PlayerPower[n_] := ResourcesToPower[PlayerResources[n]];
PlayerProvince[0] = 1;
PlayerProvince[n_] := 
  PlayerProvince[n] = 
   If[ResourcesToPower[PlayerResources[n - 1] ] >=  
     ProvincePower[PlayerProvince[n - 1] ], 
    PlayerProvince[n - 1] + 1, PlayerProvince[n - 1]]; 
p = PlayerProvince[3]
```

I'm getting error:

> "The expression
>   If[25.8496>={50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50}[1],PlayerProvince[1-1]+1,
>   PlayerProvince[1-1]] cannot be used as a part specification"

For some reason Mathematica doesn't expand expression to a number. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your third from the last line of code above change

```
ProvincePower[PlayerProvince[n - 1]]
```

to

```
ProvincePower[[PlayerProvince[n - 1]]]
```

because `ProvincePower` is an array and not a function and you need `[[value]]` to extract an element from an array or list.